# Android USB "Disk Drive" disappeared on HTC EVO V 4G (Virgin Mobile)

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb-connection-mode, htc-evo, macos

I'm not sure if it's a result of the recent upgrade to ICS 4.0.3, but when I connect my USB cable to my Mac, I no longer see the "Disk Drive" option on the Android. My only choices are:

- Charge only
- HTC Sync
- Media sync

Is something broken? How can I transfer non-media files?

I installed the HTC Sync app, but the "Files" menu option is disabled.

(Yes, I have rebooted both the phone and the Mac and have tried different USB cables.)

Comment: I believe Android 4 no longer supports USB Mass Storage Mode

Comment: @Sathya not fully correct: some manufacturers decided to not support it anymore, at least for several devices. They switched to [MTP](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtp) instead. **danorton:** I just added the corresponding tag to your question. Recommendation: Hover your mouse over it, and select the "info" link for introductionary details. You might then make your question more precise. You might also want to follow the MTP link ;)

Comment: Thanks. @Izzy, do you have a reference? I wonder if there's any way to find out for sure for my specific phone. Virgin Mobile and HTC are hopeless at revealing this level of detail, AFAICT.

Comment: @danorton I have no specific reference for your device. I just know that while Android 4.0+ still supports UMS (my tablets running 4.1.1 do support it), some manufacturers decided against it and switched to MTP (which has its pros and cons). You could ask your provider, or check with the customer service of your manufacturer. The latter should be able to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to a Mac, it's no longer a direct option, but there's an easy workaround.

1. From the Mac, download, install and start this app:

   - http://www.android.com/filetransfer/
2. The Mac app will prompt you to connect your Android.
3. Plug the Android into a USB port.
4. On the Android, select “Media sync” mode.
5. On the Mac, the file transfer app will show a window with file/folder selections.
6. On the Mac, open a Finder window, then drag and drop files back and forth between Finder and the Android File Transfer app.

*Unlike the old “Disk drive” option, the Android File Transfer app does not provide access via a mounted volume.*

Comment: Incredibly, I got to this solution via the HTC Facebook page. They redirected me to the main HTC support number and the first person answering there provided this solution.